# RGB888 to RGB565 / Bit Shifting

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, rgb

I want to combine three characters into a short using bit shifting. This is for implementing the RGB565 color palette (where there are 5 bits for red, 6 for green, 5 for blue).

Here is my example program, i'm just missing a step in the middle i think where i need to do some anding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ){
        unsigned char r, g, b;
        unsigned short rgb;

        r = 255;        // 0xFF 1111 1111
        g = 100;        // 0x64 0110 0100
        b = 50;         // 0x32 0011 0010

        r = r >> 3;     // 0x31 0001 1111
        g = g >> 2;     // 0x19 0001 1001
        b = b >> 3;     // 0x06 0000 0110

        //r = r & something; //
        //g = g & something; //
        //b = b & something; //

        // Desired result:
        //          R      G     B
        // 0xFB26 11111 011001 00110
        rgb = r | g | b;

        printf( "r 0x%x g 0x%x b 0x%x, rgb 0x%08x\n", r, g, b, rgb );
}
```

You can see my desired result at the end. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
rgb = ((r & 0b11111000) << 8) | ((g & 0b11111100) << 3) | (b >> 3);
```

We shift `r` left by 11-3=8 bits, `g` left by 5-2=3 bits and bitwise OR these with `b` shifted right by 3 bits.

Comment: That does not seem right, the `| b` part. `b` is 8 bits, but you only need to append 5 most significant of them. Should be something like `| (b >> 3)`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: yes, I think you may be right - I’m not sure why it’s the accepted answer - it looks like I hadn’t read the question properly or something. Anyway, feel free to edit and correct it.

Comment: Actually, the other two shift values were also wrong. Funny, I've made the same mistake in my project. Been wondering what's wrong with my colors, then I came here to verify if my formula is correct, and since our formulas match, I concluded the error is elsewhere :)

Comment: Thanks again for fixing this answer - it’s often the simplest bits of code where one makes the most mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for A2A. I had also faced the same issue. The below code would help you.

```
unsigned int r,g,b; // Pixel data in the RGB
unsigned char x1,x2; // The container for resulting 2 bytes

x1 = (r & 0xF8) | (g >> 5); // Take 5 bits of Red component and 3 bits of G component

x2 = ((g & 0x1C) << 3) | (b  >> 3); // Take remaining 3 Bits of G component and 5 bits of Blue component
```

You can find the python program in the GIThub.
https://github.com/ajay126z/RGB888ToRGB565-Converter

Answer (score 0):

Remember the RGB **5**-**6**-**5**. We only need 5-bits red, 6-bits green, 5-bits blue, and then combine them.

```
rgb565 = ((r>>3) << 11) | ((g>>2) << 5) | b >> 3
         ------- 5-bits
                ----------------- 6-bits
                                 ------------- 5-bits
         ------------------------------------- 16-bits
```