# 24 bit bmp to RGB565 file conversion

Tags: image-processing

I want to convert 24 bit bmp files to RGB565 format to write to a serial TFT colour display.

The size of the 24bit bmp will always be 320x240 pixels as my TFT display is 320x240

Has anyone any experience of doing this? It could be C/C++, Shell, Python, Java Script and so on...

Comment: Don't spam multiple language tags.

Comment: Are you planning to direct the output of the answer to `/dev/fb1` on a Raspberry Pi or some such?

Answer (score 2):

I would use either **NetPBM** (much smaller and lighter-weight) or **ImageMagick** (much bigger installation) to convert the `BMP` into a format that is simple to parse and then use **Perl** to convert that to RGB565 format.

I assume you are planning to write the RGB565 data to a frame buffer, so you would do something like:

```
./bmp2rgb565 image.bmp > /dev/fb1
```

So, save the following as `bmp2rgb565`:

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# bmp2rgb565
# Mark Setchell
################################################################################

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then 
   echo Usage: $0 image.bmp
   exit 1
fi

file=$1

# Use NetPBM's "bmptopnm" to convert BMP to PNM for easy reading
# You could use ImageMagick: convert "$file" PNM: | perl ...
bmptopnm "$file" 2> /dev/null | 
   perl -e '
      my $debug=0;   # Change to 1 for debugging

      # Discard first 3 lines of PNM header:
      #   P3
      #   320 240
      #   255
      my $line=<STDIN>; $line=<STDIN>; $line=<STDIN>;

      # Read file, 3 RGB bytes at a time
      {
         local $/ = \3;
         while(my $pixel=<STDIN>){
            # Extract 8-bit R,G and B from pixel
            my ($r,$g,$b)=unpack("CCC",$pixel);
            printf("R/G/B: %d/%d/%d\n",$r,$g,$b) if $debug;

            # Convert to RGB565
            my $r5=$r>>3;
            my $g6=$g>>2;
            my $b5=$b>>3;
            my $rgb565 = ($r5<<11) | ($g6<<5) | $b5;

            # Convert to little-endian 16-bit (VAX order) and write 2 bytes
            my $v=pack("v",$rgb565);
            syswrite(STDOUT,$v,2);
         }
      }
   '
```

I don't have a frame buffer handy to test, but it should be pretty close.

Note that you could make the code more robust by starting off with:

```
convert "$file" -depth 8 -resize 320x240\! PNM: | perl ...
```

which would make sure the image always matches the framebuffer size, and that it is 8-bit and not 16-bit. You may also want a `-flip` or `-flop` in there if the `BMP` image is upside-down or back-to-front.

Note that if you use **ImageMagick** `convert`, the code will work for GIFs, TIFFs, JPEGs, PNGs and around 150 other formats as well as BMP.

---

Note that if you want to test the code, you can generate a black image with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
convert -size 320x240 xc:black BMP3:black.bmp
```

and then look for a bunch of zeroes in the output if you run:

```
./bmp2rgb565 black.bmp | xxd -g2
```

Likewise, you can generate a white image and look for a bunch of `ff`s:

```
convert -size 320x240 xc:red BMP3:white.bmp
```

And so on with red, green and blue:

```
convert -size 320x240 xc:red  BMP3:red.bmp
convert -size 320x240 xc:lime BMP3:green.bmp
convert -size 320x240 xc:blue BMP3:blue.bmp

# Or make a cyan-magenta gradient image
convert -size 320x240 gradient:cyan-magenta  cyan-magenta-gradient.bmp
```

**Example:**

```
./RGB565 red.bmp | xxd -g2 | more
00000000: 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8  ................
00000010: 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8 00f8  ................
```

**Example:**

```
./RGB565 blue.bmp | xxd -g2 | more
00000000: 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00  ................
00000010: 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00 1f00  ................
```

**Keywords:** RGB565, rgb565, framebuffer, frame-buffer, pack, unpack, Perl, BMP, PGM, image, Raspberry Pi, RASPI

Answer (score 0):

To convert to RGB565 you can use ImageMagick:

```
convert test.png -resize 320x200 -ordered-dither threshold,32,64,32 test2.png
```

In what format do you need the output to be?

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. OP says image will always be 320x240 so what's the point of resizing it all? And if there is a point, why resize to 320x200? Also, OP wants output in RGB565, but you have created a PNG which clearly isn't RGB565.

Comment: It is. 32,65,32 is 2^5 , 2^6 , 2^5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you simply want to stream out the pixel data without any headers or additional data.

The core of the problem has already been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471122/rgb888-to-rgb565-bit-shifting).

If you want to implement it for yourself, the following approach will probably help:

After opening the file, yout need to skip the BMP header by reading the `bfOffBits` value (see [this BMP format description](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm)), the easiest way would probably be to implement it in C by reading into a struct that matches the BMP header.

(Note: This only works because the dimensions of the image are divisible by 4! Check the format description for more details)

Then seek forward by `bfOffBits` and while the file has not ended, transform three consecutive bytes (`uint8_t`) to one 16 bit value (`uint16_t`) by using the approach from the question I mentioned above. The basic C file operations you would need are `fopen, fclose, fread, fwrite, fgetc/fgetwc, fputc/fputwc` and `fseek`