# Convert image to BMP RGB565 without BMP header

Tags: imagemagick

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and Imagemagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 arm 20170114 to convert a file to RGB565 and display it on a 480x320 screen (The image pixel dimensions are also 480x320) by writing it to the framebuffer. I'm using the following convert command:

> convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 bmp2:out.bmp

The expected filesize is 307,200 bytes. The actual filesize is coming in slightly higher due to the header data. Currently I am using dd to remove X number of bytes from the start of the file to make the file 307,200.

E.g. if the filesize is 307,338, I'm running the following command:

> dd bs=138 skip=1 if=out.bmp of=out.trimmed.bmp

Once the file is trimmed and has a filesize of 307,200 I can write the file to the framebuffer

> cat out.trimmed.bmp > /dev/fb1

Does anyone have any insight on how to update the convert command to simply omit the header data? I would like to cut out the middle steps and simply use Imagemagick to write directly to the framebuffer.

> convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 bmp2:/dev/fb1

I have attempted the following commands, but they all create a file that is much larger than my required filesize of 307,200.

> convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 rgb:0-rgb.bmp
>
> convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 rgba:0-rgba.bmp
>
> convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 dib:0-dib.bmp

I have tested fbi (fim) (framebuffer imageviewer) to do this and the program is not ideal for my needs. I have also tested ffmpeg to do the conversion, but it's resource heavy and slow.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Improved Answer**

Rather than guessing how big the (variable) header is, it is probably simpler to just take the tail-end of the file. So, if you know your frame buffer is 480x320 and 2 bytes per pixel, i.e. RGB565, use:

```
convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 bmp2:- | tail -c $((480*320*2)) > /dev/fb1
```

That arithmetic expression is admittedly a `bash-ism`, but Raspbian has `bash` anyway, and it can be replaced with:

```
convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 bmp2:- | tail -c 307200 > /dev/fb1
```

**Original Answer**

Like this:

```
convert dmi.jpg +flip -strip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 bmp2:- | dd bs=138 skip=1 > /dev/fb1
```

**Explanation**:

`bmp2:-` will make **ImageMagick** write a BMP2 on `stdout`. By default, `dd` will read `stdin` and write `stdout` which is then redirected to the framebuffer.

Comment: I'm not sure of the variables involved, but through some quick testing I am not having a consistent header size of 138 bytes. In some cases I've had it as low as 23 bytes. Do you know of any Imagemagick methods to normalize the header if it cannot be fully removed?

Comment: You could try `convert ... bmp2:- | tail -c 307200 > /dev/fb1` to just take the last 307200 bytes regardless of header length. Or look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854343/2836621

Comment: Replacing dd with tail solved the final piece of this.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project! Come back if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free :-)