# How to convert hex to decimal rgb565 using java?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, hex, rgb

I'm trying make program which convert hex to decimal rgb888 and rgb565 respectively.

I’m already did my program to convert hex to rgb888 format, and my code looks like this:

```
String color = "0xFFFF00";
    int hexToRgb = 0;

    color.toLowerCase();
    String[] colorSplited = color.split("0x");
    String splitedConverted = colorSplited[1];

    int R = Integer.valueOf(splitedConverted.substring(0,2), 16);
    int G = Integer.valueOf(splitedConverted.substring(2,4), 16);
    int B = Integer.valueOf(splitedConverted.substring(4,6), 16);

    System.out.println(R + " " + G + " " + B);
```

I saw some articles where they explained that each rgb888 component R, G and B is variated by 0 and 2^8. My currently program don’t use that specific process but I got the results which I needed.

Now I need make the same program but to convert hex to rgb565,. My hex input looks like this:

```
String color = “0xFFE0”;
```

So which will be converted is FFE0.

To this input I need get the result R = 31, G = 63 and B = 0. But I have no idea how I achieve this result.
What I got in the internet was to each component RGB is variated by 0 <= R <= 2^5, 0 <= G <=  2^6 and 0 <=B <= 2^5.

Unfortunately I’m not an expert in math.
Can someone help me understand the math behind this or have any sugestions about how I can get this result?

Comment: Try looking at [RGB888 to RGB565 / Bit Shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471122/rgb888-to-rgb565-bit-shifting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, each hexadecimal character is codified by 4 bits. Therefore, having 4 hex characters means you have 16 bits to code a color.

RGB565 uses 5 bits for red, 6 bits for green and 5 bits for blue. Having **n** bits for a color means it'll have **2^n** possible values. 2^5 = 32 and 2^6 = 64, this is where the different values for each color you got from the Internet come from.

To split the RGB565 value into each separate color you would need to extract the corresponding bits for each one of them, for example, like this:

```
int redMask   = 0b1111100000000000;
int greenMask = 0b0000011111100000;
int blueMask  = 0b0000000000011111;

String color = "0xFFE0";
int colorAsInteger = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(2,color.length()), 16); // convert the Hex value to int

int R = (colorAsInteger & redMask) >> 11; // keep only red bits
int G = (colorAsInteger & greenMask) >> 5; // keep only green bits
int B = colorAsInteger & blueMask; // keep only blue bits

System.out.println(R + " " + G + " " + B);
```

Comment: you code help me to achieve my goal, and the first answer that I got help me understand better the math behind this. So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The typical hex representation of RGB colors is the same as RGB888, i'll try to show this with examples. Guess we've got the color

`0xFF8800`, which is literally

`1111.1111.1000.1000.0000.0000` as a binary number, where its components are:

`R = FF = 1111.1111` = 255(dots are only for helping the view)

`G = 88 = 1000.1000` = 136

`B = 00 = 0000.0000` = 0

So, the translation is immediate (well, there's no translation indeed), and each component can have a value from 00 to FF (0 to 255 in decimal base)

The case with RGB565 is different. You only have 5 bits (or 6 in case of green) to represent that component of the color.

You can see each component as the percentage of participation in the global color.

In the example of `0xFF8800`:

Red component participates with a 100% (it has the maximum possible value for a component, 255)

Green participates with a 53.33% (it has the value 136 over 255)

Blue participates with a 0%, this one is obvious.

If you apply this percentages of color to the RGB565 color, you will got the values of each component.

So, to translate `0xFF8800` to RGB565, calculate each percentage

```
R = 1 * 31 = 31 //(percentage over 100 by the maximum value of red in RGB565 = 2^5, minus 1)

G = 0.5333 * 63 = 33.6 //(you should round this value to integer)

B = 0 * 31 = 0
```

With this, the final number is:

```
  31    34    0
```

`11111.100010.00000`

```
      or
```

`1111.1100.0100.0000`

```
     in hex
```

`0xFC40`

Not sure if the explanation is the best, but hope it helps.

Comment: Your math explanation helped me understand a bit better what the computer really doing to process this. I will make some paper exercises to practice a bit your theory and keep the explanation in mind, I don't like just copy and paste code, generally I like to understand how the math really works too. Thanks @alseether

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply split the string like you were doing for the rgb888 format.
What you should do is converting the full string to a number and then split this number using bit shifting like this :

```
    String color = "0xFFE0";
    int rgb = Integer.valueOf(color.substring(2,6), 16);
    int r = (rgb & 0b1111100000000000) >> 11;
    int g = (rgb & 0b0000011111100000) >> 5;
    int b = (rgb & 0b0000000000011111) >> 0;
```

Comment: Got it! I'll make this change. I have not noticed that I not needed that line